# Is Fourier transform method suitable for solving equation $\int g(x-t)e^{-t^2} dt = e^{-a|x|}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is Fourier transform method suitable for  to solve  the following equation 
\begin{align*}
\int g(x-t)e^{-t^2/2} dt = e^{-a|x|}
\end{align*}

Suppose we take the Fourier transform of the above equation
\begin{align*}
&G(\omega) \sqrt{2\pi} e^{-\omega^2/2}=\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}\\
&G(\omega)=\frac{2e^{\omega^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+\omega^2)}
\end{align*}

But the function on the right is not integrable. What can we do in case like this?
Is there a strategy to solving general cases like this?

Comment: Is there a typo on the r.h.s.? Should it it be $e^{-a|x|}$?

Comment: yes. there is. will correct. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform method is useful in showing that there is no solution.

Since $G$ is unbounded, what your argument shows is that there is no solution in $L^1$. It is clear also that $G$ is not in $L^2$, so that the is no solution in $L^2$. Moreover, $G$ is not a tempered distribution, so that there is no solution in the space of tempered distributions.

Comment: Why is G not tempered distribution?

Comment: It grows too fast at $\infty$. $f(\omega)=e^{-\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}$ is a function in the Schwarz space $\mathcal{S}$, and $f\,G$ is not integrable.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do you know of any text that show how to use Fourier analysis to solve integral or convolution equations?